# Open the card that was clicked on, not all cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please help me figure it out. How, with such a component structure, to implement the opening of the card to the full screen?

It is necessary to open the card on which the click was made.
The click is not on the card itself but on the button `<FullScreenButton />`.

Is there a method to implement this? In the current version of my code, two cards are opened at once.

```
export const ChartsContainer: FC = () => {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={styles.chartsContainer}>
      <Grid container className={styles.panelContainerWrapper} wrap="nowrap">
        <Grid item xs={6} className={styles.panelContainer}>
          <ChartContainer `<------------------------------------------------card`
            title="title1"
            open={open}
            feature={
              <div className={styles.featureWrapper}>
                <p className={styles.featureText}>
                  {data.chartRequestData.totalRequests.toLocaleString()}
                </p>
                <FullScreenButton onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}> `<-------button`
                  <IconOpenInFull />
                </FullScreenButton>
              </div>
            }
          >
            <>
              <LineBar data={data.chartRequestData.request} type="line" />
              <ChartLegend />
            </>
          </ChartContainer>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} className={styles.panelContainer}>
          <ChartContainer
            open={open}
            title="title2"
            feature={
              <div className={styles.featureWrapper}>
                <CustomSelect
                  variant="secondary"
                  options={chartSelectOptions}
                />
                <FullScreenButton onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                  <IconOpenInFull />
                </FullScreenButton>
              </div>
            }
          >
            <LineBar
              data={data.chartFoivData.request.maxIndicators}
              type="bar"
            />
          </ChartContainer>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

ChartContainer.tsx

```
export const ChartContainer: FC<ChartContainerProps> = ({
  feature,
  title,
  children,
  className,
  open,
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={cn(styles.panelWrapper, className, {
        [styles.panelFull]: open,
      })}
    >
      <div className={styles.headerWrapper}>
        <h3 className={styles.title}>{title}</h3>
        {feature}
      </div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi jakiehan! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are making is that you are using one `open` state for the two cards. You should have as many states as cards to have them individually opened, something like so:

```js
export const ChartsContainer: FC = () => {
  const [openFirstChart, setOpenFirstChard] = useState(false);
  const [openSecondChart, setOpenSecondChart] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={styles.chartsContainer}>
      <Grid container className={styles.panelContainerWrapper} wrap="nowrap">
        <Grid item xs={6} className={styles.panelContainer}>
          <ChartContainer
            title="title1"
            open={openFirstChart}
            feature={
              <div className={styles.featureWrapper}>
                <p className={styles.featureText}>
                  {data.chartRequestData.totalRequests.toLocaleString()}
                </p>
                <FullScreenButton onClick={() => setOpenFirstChard(!openFirstChart)}>
                  <IconOpenInFull />
                </FullScreenButton>
              </div>
            }
          >
            <>
              <LineBar data={data.chartRequestData.request} type="line" />
              <ChartLegend />
            </>
          </ChartContainer>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} className={styles.panelContainer}>
          <ChartContainer
            open={openSecondChart}
            title="title2"
            feature={
              <div className={styles.featureWrapper}>
                <CustomSelect variant="secondary" options={chartSelectOptions} />
                <FullScreenButton onClick={() => setOpenSecondChart(!openSecondChart)}>
                  <IconOpenInFull />
                </FullScreenButton>
              </div>
            }
          >
            <LineBar data={data.chartFoivData.request.maxIndicators} type="bar" />
          </ChartContainer>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```